# How to get last scroll position a of WebView

Tags: java, android, html, css, webview

i'm using `WebView` to show a long static post. so i need to save last position that user was reading and restore that position later.

how can i do it?

i tried to get WebView's scroll position percentage but getScrollY() returns 0

i overrided the onScrollChange() method of WebView but it seems that this is not calling onScrollChange() method when i'm scrolling the page.

my HTML sample code:

```html
<html>
   <head>
   <style>
   someStyle ... no position style here
   }</style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div><html>
    <head></head> 
    <body> 
     <table> 
      <tbody> 
       <tr> 
        <td> 
          <p align="left"><font size="1" color="#FF0000">[</font></p> <p align="left" style="line-height: 130%"><font>someText</font></p> 
       </tr> 
      </tbody> 
     </table>  
    </body>
   </html>
   </html>
```

my get Percentage method:

```
 private float calculateProgression(WebView content) {
    float positionTopView = content.getTop();
    float contentHeight = content.getContentHeight();
    float currentScrollPosition = content.getScrollY();
    float percentWebview = (currentScrollPosition - positionTopView) / contentHeight;
    return percentWebview;
}
```

Comment: Have you check this before posting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); if you want how far the listView contents are scrolled.

Comment: it's a WebView : /

Comment: webView always return 0 for getScrollY() ... that's the problem : /

Comment: @Mehrad Were you able to get a solution to this issue?